# Impossible math - number needs to be divisible and greater than an end result

Tags: functions, soft-question

I'm working on a capture the flag event and I'm being presented with the following.

```
Solve for X, where:
X > 66759
X * 9 = 66759
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how this could work and I think there's potentially a gap in my mathematical knowledge causing it. What do I need to learn to understand how a scenario like this is possible? Or is it truly not possible?

I've already tried returning decimal results, however they aren't considered integers and are rejected. The same result happens if you try strings.

If this is truly impossible I'd love to know as potentially this needs to be tackled from another security angle, and not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to solve this equation, taking into account integer overflow. For example, if you work with 32-bit signed integers, the largest value you can represent is $2^{31}-1 = 2147483647$. If you add 1 to that number, you get $-2^{32}$. Mathematically speaking, this means you're working *modulo* $2^{32}$ and your equations become:

$$x > 66759$$

$$9x = 66759 \mod 2^{32}$$

The multiplicative inverse of 9 (modulo $2^{32}$) is 954437177 (found by trying $n \cdot 2^{32} + 1$ for $n=1,2,$ etc.). The following simple Java program will show that, in the context of signed 32 bit integers, $x = 1431663183$ is a solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 954437177 * 66759;
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(x > 66759);
    System.out.println(x * 9);
}
```

This prints the following:

> 1431663183
>   true
>   66759

Answer (score 2):

The second restriction $9X = 66759$ completely determines the value of $X$.

Divide both sides by $9$ to get $X = \displaystyle \frac{66759}{9} = 7417.66 \ldots$.

Clearly $ 7417.66 \ldots \not > 66759$ and so no value of $X$ satisfies both restrictions.

You cannot solve for $X$ because no such $X$ exists.

Comment: I did think this would be the case - just seeking clarification before I probed further into the host. Thank-you!